# Why booleans take a whole byte?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++. In todays lesson I came to know that a boolean variable takes a total byte. Why? A Boolean  evaluates to either true or false and a single bit is enough for storing 1 for true and 0 for false. What it does with those extra 7 bits?

Comment: It's just that you can't allocate less than one word of memory.

Comment: and even if the compiler was to combine the booleans into a bitfield, it would not allow you to get a pointer to your boolean. or get the sizeof() your boolean. bitfields would work in other languages where this detail is hidden. but not in C++ where & and sizeof() etc are requirements on types.